# Is there a way to broadcast Kafka messages from a specific timestamp (currentTimeStamp - 2 min) to a new SSE consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, server-sent-events

Is there a way to broadcast Kafka messages from a specific timestamp (e.g., currentTimestamp - 2 min) to a new Server-Sent-Event (SSE) consumer?

I have one multi-partition Kafka topic and multiple SSE client. I tried implementing AbstractConsumerSeekAware and use seekToTimestamp in the SSE controller but that's not working out. Its basically broadcasting the seek to all the SSE clients.

I want it only for the SSE client that newly joined.

Below is my code:

```
public class ServerController extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware {

......

@GetMapping(path = "/stream/{orgid}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    Flux<ServerSentEvent<ServiceEvent>> getFolderWatch(@PathVariable String orgid) {
        return Flux.create(sink -> {
                    this.seekToTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 2 * 60 * 1000);
                    MessageHandler handler = message -> sink.next((ServiceEvent) message.getPayload());
                    sink.onCancel(() -> subscribableChannel.unsubscribe(handler));
                    subscribableChannel.subscribe(handler);
                }, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST)
                .filter(receiveRecord -> {
                    ServiceEvent event = (ServiceEvent) receiveRecord;
                    return event.getOrgId().equals(orgid);
                }).map(e -> {
                    ServiceEvent event = (ServiceEvent) e;
                    return ServerSentEvent.<ServiceEvent>builder(event).build();
                });
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${topic.name.consumer}", groupId = "my-sse-application")
    public void listenGroupFoo(@Payload String content) {
        logger.info("Received Message in group foo: " + content);
        subscribableChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>(new ServiceEvent(this, content)));
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you tracking when SSE clients join?

Comment: I'm not tracking it manually at the moment, but I can use a map 
`private final Map<String, SseEmitter> emitters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`
to track the clients, and redirect kafka messages there

Comment: Okay, well, you'll need to track somewhere to find "new clients" vs "existing clients", but I wouldn't suggest a Map unless clients must always reconnect when your Spring app restarts.

Comment: so we have this orgID field in the Kafka message, and I take the same orgID in the path variable for the SSE client's request. Now I have to filter out messages with timestamp seeks and send it to the new clients. Let's say we find a way to track new vs existing clients somehow, how can we achieve this?

Comment: Isn't that what you're code already is doing? You've not shown your seekToTimestamp method, but seems to me like any orgId will always seek the exact same data, so what tests have you done for multiple requests coming at the same time?

Comment: i am using the 'seekToTimestamp' method provided by the AbstractConsumerSeekAware class

Comment: Sure, but your app only has one consumer? So all GET requests for any org will seek the same consumer? And then recreate **all** ServiceEvent objects in the last 2 minutes (not only those specific to the org)? Basically, I think you want an in memory database that tracks what clients are registered, then run a window scan query against that. Only use Kafka consumer to dump to that database, not send out SSE

Comment: agreed, I was thinking in that direction as well. But wanted to discuss what if I have multiple instances of this service. Should I treat each replica as a different consumer? Otherwise, I will have to store somehow a mapping of which SSE consumer has connected to which service replica and keep the Kafka event in the corresponding one.

Comment: one more thing is, I obviously don't want to keep all the Kafka records in the in-memory DB forever, so I would need an eviction strategy for it as well. Do you think we can utilize any out-of-box solution for that?

Comment: You could try using Kafka Streams interactive queries. Then send tombstone events to evict records from those tables. Otherwise, any database that supports range queries should work fine